# "Helocoidal " surface of Gauss curvature -1

Tags: differential-geometry

What  (2 parameter) parametrisation holds for a surface Gauss curvature = -1 spanned between two helices:

$$  ( \cos t, \sin t, t)  ( -\cos t, -\sin t, t) ? $$

$ t= constant$  as a parameter does  not satisfy the requirement as we know mean curvature $H=0$ for the classical helicoid.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  (And is it clear that there even exists such a surface you seek?)

Comment: I cannot prove existence or uniqueness. My belief stems from       http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.04876                                                               David Brander, Technical university of Denmark has indicated possibility of spanning constant negative Gauss curvature surfaces between arbitrary cuspidal line boundaries (he refers to them as pseudo spherical frontals).

Comment: I for one think that definition of such boundaries for  ( K = -1)  constitutes a problem that ranks with Plateau's problem for ( H=0).

Comment: Dini's surface is pretty much the closest thing one has to a "helicoidal" surafce with constant negative curvature.

Comment: Sir, By addition of a shear term, a single cuspy equator of Beltrami pseudosphere is twisted to become a spiral in a Dini. Starting with hyperbolic or elliptic types ( with an extra constant ) can we not, likewise twist them by shear to obtain many cuspidal helical edges? Regards.

Comment: @J.M. http://virtualmathmuseum.org/Surface/gallery_o.html ;   Dini's surface is single soliton solution, there is a 2- soliton solution also.  To what extent is the latter surface, enclosed between two helices, could approximate to an answer to the question?

Comment: I haven't really tried, but: why not try to build the parametric equations from your two-soliton solution via Codazzi-Mainardi?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following form
\begin{align*}
  \boldsymbol{x}(u,v) &=
  \begin{pmatrix} u \cos v \\ u \sin v \\ v+a u+O(u^{2}) \end{pmatrix} \\[5pt]
  K &=\frac{-1+O(u^{3})}{1+(1+a^{2})u^{2}+O(u^{3})} \\
\end{align*}

To match the boundary condition, $a=n\pi$.

$K=-1$ only when $u=0$, (meaningless for $a^{2}=-1$).

**P.S.:**
I've tried to solve the differential equation with $z(u,v)=v+f(u)$, but the surface is disconnected.  Whereas for $z=vf(u)$ gives $v$-dependence in $K$.

Comment: It has  similar behaviour as the helicoid, as  K not exactly -1 everywhere.